# C# Linq, object definition does not contains a property

Tags: c#, linq

I need your help

I just wrote the following code

```
var anynomousObject = new { Amount = 10, weight = 20 };

List<object> ListOfAnynomous = new List<object> { anynomousObject };
var productQuery =
            from prod in ListOfAnynomous
            select new { prod.Amount, prod.weight }; // here it object on 'prod.Amount, prod.weight' that the object defenetion does not contains the "Amount" and "weight" properties

 foreach (var v in productQuery)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(v.Amount, v.weight);
  }
```

so please could you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Try `List<dynamic>` instead of `List<object>`

Comment: Because it is a anonymous object, and you box it in a list of object, the compiler doesn't know the definition of your anonymous object when you box it. You need, if you want a list of, to make class or struct, only work around is dynamic

Comment: You cannot use `object` and expect that you can use all properties or methods without casting. But casting to an anonymous type is not possible (easily). Have a look at Jon Skeets `GrottyHacks.Cast` method which casts by example. http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance/ Your `anynomousObject` would be the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a class of your object definition, or using the dynamic keywork instead of boxing in object :

```
 var anynomousObject = new { Amount = 10, weight = 20 };

 List<dynamic> ListOfAnynomous = new List<dynamic> { anynomousObject };
 var productQuery =
                    from prod in ListOfAnynomous
                    select new { prod.Amount, prod.weight }; 

 foreach (var v in productQuery)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(v.Amount, v.weight);
 }
```

this is because, when you box as object, the compiler doesn't know the definition of your anonymous var. Dynamic make it evaluate at runtime instead of compile-time.

The other option is to create a class or struct.

Comment: Thanks @cdie but what is the difference between the  List<dynamic>  and  List<object> in this case

Comment: thanks a lot, I got it, great answer, I will accept it but the site does not allow me to accept answers before 8 mins left on the answer

Comment: You can google for the difference between dynamic and object. It's pretty easy to find.

Comment: @cosmo0 it is better to get the answer while discussing, it will be memorized better

Answer (score 1):

Your `List<object>` has a list of `object`s. The Linq query looks this list, and all it sees are regular `object`s.

Either use a class or a structure to store your objects, or use `List<dynamic>`