# Why in c# can't we wrap anonymous objects in list of objects?

Tags: c#, linq, compilation, runtime

Why in c# can't we wrap anonymous objects in list of objects?
For Example I have seen [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274730/c-sharp-linq-object-definition-does-not-contains-a-property) in StackOverFlow  `C# Linq, object definition does not contains a property`

```
var anynomousObject = new { Amount = 10, weight = 20 };

List<object> ListOfAnynomous = new List<object> { anynomousObject, anynomousObject };
var productQuery =
            from prod in ListOfAnynomous
            select new { prod.Amount, prod.weight };

foreach (var v in productQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.Amount);
    Console.WriteLine(v.weight);
}
```

and the answer was that he should wrap the anonymous in list of `dynamic` but actually I can't understand why in the run time we can't get their values.

Comment: how exactly you ***wrapped the anonymous in list of dynamic***? I've just made a simple test and looks like `from dynamic prod in ...` works.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous types are also types and they're compiled into actual classes. **That is, *anonymous* doesn't mean *untyped*.**

If you add anonymous type instances to a `List<object>` you're *upcasting* them to `object` and you lose the typing itself, thus, you can't access anonymous type instance properties.

Instead of storing them in a `List<dynamic>`, you should go with other solution: store in a generic list of anonymous type. Since you don't gain access to anonymous type names (*it's anonymous, they've no name - well, they compile into actual classes, but this is how internally works at compile/run time, it's a low-level detail*), you can't use explicit typing, but C# has type-inferred variables:

```
// compiles to string a = "hello"; assignment defines the type
var a = "hello";
```

...so, what about this?

```
// Use a type-inferred array to define the items and then convert the array
// to list!
// Now you can use each anonymous type instance properties in LINQ ;)
var listOfAnonymousInstances = new [] { new { Amount = 10, weight = 20 } }.ToList();
// If you mouse over the var keyword, you'll find that it's a List<a`>!
```